# Difficulty with python package mgrs by Howard Butler

Tags: python, python-2.7, mgrs

I am developing an app in python and I am trying to import Howard Butler's mgrs package.  I am using setuptools to install the package.  It does not find the setuptools library module.  I have tried modifying the setup.py that comes with the mgrs 1.3.1 package to import library from setuptools.extension with no luck.  As a result, i cannot get the libmgrs.dll created.  Does anyone have an idea about what I can do to make this work?

Comment: [mgrs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mgrs) is not a standard Python module, it is also a wrapper around C functions. So you need to compile these C files. If you are on Windows, you cannot (no native C compilers as in Linux or Mac OS X). If you use these OS, a simple `python setup.py install` installs the module.

Comment: I am on Windows.

Comment: so, sorry, it will be difficult...